# What's the grammar of "specified in here" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I heard this through VOA, but I wonder if its grammar is correct.

> I don't see anywhere specified in here exactly what the fraud was.

My idea is: the word "anywhere" in this sentence is an adverb modifying "see"; "exactly what the fraud was" is the object, but what is "specified in here" in the sentence?

The original text is here:

> Falsifying a business record is a crime if it is part of a fraudulent scheme and **I don't see anywhere specified in here exactly what the fraud was**, but there are a host of other problems having to do with the statute of limitations, his failure to specify exactly what the other crime was that was being committed that makes this into a felony.

Comment: It looks as though the person was speaking 'off the cuff', and the whole sentence is ungrammatical. Presumably they meant to say "I don't see it specified anywhere in here exactly what the fraud was", where 'here' refers to a document.

Comment: @Joachim Oh, sorry. There shouldn't be an "In" in this sentence. It's probably a subtitle error. I saw it on a Chinese English-learning website, but I can't find the link to the original video now. If you're interested, the link to the video on that website is here. I'm not sure if you can access it. The sentence is around 1:06.https://dict.eudic.net/webting/videoplay/b16d666b-deb0-11ed-80e8-005056866eda

Comment: @KateBunting Many thanks! But there's another question: In the sentence "I don't see it specified anywhere in here exactly what the fraud was", is "it" the formal object and "exactly what the fraud was" is the logical object of "see"?

Comment: @Joachim I found the same sentence in Fox News. You can search for this sentence “I don't see anywhere specified in here exactly what the fraud was” on the webpage: https://www.foxnews.com/politics/barr-slams-trump-weak-candidate-makes-bold-prediction-2024-election

Comment: I had to look up what a 'formal object' is, but, yes, _it_ seems to be one in my sentence.